# I need to identify the REST API's Problem

Tags: api, wordpress-rest-api, rest

API 1 : Below is a very bad REST API that takes a user id and returns the user details. Identify 3 problems with this.

```
REQUEST:
POST /getUsers/1

RESPONSE: status: 200

[
{
"id": "1",
"name": "John Doe"
}
]
```

API 2 : What is wrong with the following API response representing a validation error?

```
RESPONSE status: 500
{
"code": "bad.request",
"message": "request.query.limit should be <= 100",
"timestamp": "2019-08-22T06:00:00.000Z",
}
```

Comment: API 1 should be a GET, not POST, it should return an object, not an array if it's just getting one user. API 2 should be a status code of 400, not 500.

Comment: This is not a homework solving service.

Answer (score -1):

API 1:

1. it should be a GET request, since you are fetching user data and not a POST which is for creating a new resource
2. the endpoint URI should be restructured to something like `/users/:id`. the 'getUser' in the URI is a bad naming practice for RESTful APIs (the CRUD action should be specified in the HTTP request method (e.g. GET method in this case), not in the URI.)
3. The response body contains an array of json objects, it should be a json of json objects instead.

API 2:

Based on the error code and message, this error is a bad request error for which a HTTP status code of 400 should be returned instead. A bad request error si caused by the client; whereas, a 500 error is an internal server error which is for when the server is at fault.

Comment: In regards to 2) this is nonsense actually. In a true REST environment, the characters that form the URI may and probably should not make sense to a client at all as this just invites client programmers to [consider a resources being of a certain type](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html). If so, the media-type negotiated is missing in those samples. The last point also tackles your 3) point in some way as the response format is dependant on the negotiated media-type. If you will you might even argue whether the ID within the response is needed or the like

Comment: In regards to the error code, `429 Too Many Requests` might be even more fitting. Just skim through the [list of registered status codes](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml). Also, instead of sending out arbitrary errors it would be beneficial to stick to available representation formats, i.e. such as [`application/problem+json`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7807). Please, if you answer  obviously homework questions, put in a bit more research first